# Use datepicker to get date range in jquery 1.6.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, date, datepicker

I'm trying to add a jquery datepicker in a jsp page to get a date range as input.
Following is the code I have currently.

```
$(function() {
        $( "#createdAtFrom" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#createdAtTo" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
            }
        });
        $( "#createdAtTo" ).datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
                $( "#createdAtFrom" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });
    });
```

When I used this I'm getting a undefined value at onclose method, so once I open the datepicker and then close it, I no longer get the calander to load. I'm using jquery 1.6.3, is it possible to get this to work and how can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code solved the issue.

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#createdAtFrom").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#createdAtTo").datepicker({minDate:
                        new Date($('#createdAtFrom').datepicker("getDate"))});
            }
        });
        $("#createdAtTo").datepicker({
            defaultDate: "+1w",
            changeMonth: true,
            numberOfMonths: 1,
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#createdAtFrom").datepicker({maxDate: new
                        Date($('#createdAtTo').datepicker("getDate"))});
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

source :- http://cdwijayarathna.blogspot.com/2015/10/adding-jquery-datepicker-to-select-date.html

Answer (score 0):

This code is runnig successfully in my jsp page. Hope so this will work you too.

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from, #to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 3,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            if(this.id == 'from'){
              var dateMin = $('#from').datepicker("getDate");
              var rMin = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 1); 
              var rMax = new Date(dateMin.getFullYear(), dateMin.getMonth(),dateMin.getDate() + 61); 
              $('#from').datepicker("option","minDate",rMin);                  $('#to').datepicker("option","maxDate",rMax);                    
            }

        }
    });
});
```

Comment: what is the version of jquery you are using?

Comment: i am using jquery 1.6

Comment: in my project i gave two month gap between two date, so i can search data between two month so i mention tha gap in "var rMin" , which 61... you can change this as per you requirment

Comment: What I need is, to table's value should always be greater than from tables value if from has a value, and from's value should always be less than to's value if it has a value, it seems like both of us has used the same method for setting the 'minDate' and 'maxDate', your code also gives the same error here.

Comment: use this link. may this help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028465/jquery-ui-datepicker-date-range